# Do missed vigors become available at vendors later? If so, approximately when?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

So I missed the first opportunity to pick up the Murder of Crows vigor - apparently it must have "landed" further away from the body than usual. I've heard people say the vigors (at least the ones you miss as drops) become available for purchase later, but I haven't seen this one pop up yet. Does anyone know if/when they do?

Comment: While I haven't missed any vigors and thus can't speak to if or when they appear in vendors, I can say that you'll occasionally find ones you already have laying around on later levels. If you already have that vigor, it just treats it as +salt when you pick it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked I missed out the charge vigour during the game. At the last stage i found it selling for 250$ in the vigour vending machine so yes they do sell it. if you happen to see a vigour skills in shop and you don't have it means your are able to buy it from the shop.

Comment: I can confirm now, that they do. Just before I got the "quest" to go find the shock jockey vigor, one of the Veni Vidi Vigor machines had Murder of Crows.

Answer (score 3):

As you progress through the game, you will find repeat vigors. So, if you missed one, not to worry. You will easily another one of the same type as you progress through the game. There must be like 10s of them. If you find a vigor you already have, it will simply replenish your salt.

I am unsure whether vendors sell them later or not. I believe they do if you progress far enough.